# Cygwin graphics?

Tags: c, graphics, netbeans, cygwin

I am currently using Netbeans with Cygwin on windows 7, and i'm looking to write a simple 2D game in C.

Most of the tutorials i've managed to find use the graphics.h supplied with Turbo C, does Cygwin have an alternative to this? Any info about how to get another header file installed, or links to tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Why don't you try Qt? If you can code in C++.

Answer (score 0):

[SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) is a good library to use for basic game graphics. Note that Cygwin is not needed (unless you really need POSIX emulation) - Mingw will usually suffice.

Comment: Cygwin was suggested on some tutorial as Netbeans needs the compiler, thanks for the reply shall look at both :)